# Including external markdown content with Assemble.io

Tags: assemble

working to get external content included with other `.hbs` files and unable to get it to work.

I have installed `handlebars-helper-md` and loading.

Based on the [docs here](http://assemble.io/docs/Markdown.html) - I have tried:

```
---
content: ../path/to/content.md
---
{{md  content }}
```

*and*

```
{{md  '.. /path /to /content.md '}}
```

I have tried every possible file path I could think of to get the file to render, and have gotten nothing to display.

Is the file path relative to the current directory I'm in? Is this target/task oriented in grunt?  Any other directions or things I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - a little more trial and error, as well as reviewing the [Github readme](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-md) helped me figure this out.

I included the files in the options object:

```
assemble: {
   options: {
       partials: 'my/partials/directory/*.md'
   }
}
```

And was then easily able to do this:

```
{{md 'myfile'}}
```

Working great now.